# Paypal SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR

Tags: android, paypal-android-sdk

I am working on integrating `Paypal` payment with my android app.

This is my `Paypal` configuration code :

```
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Integration Demo")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse(""))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"))
        .rememberUser(true);
```

and here i am calling `PayPalService` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(intent);
```

But i am getting following error :

```
01-11 11:49:19.788 31868-8284/com.packagename E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:shutdown
01-11 11:49:19.803 31868-31868/com.packagename E/paypal.sdk: SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR
```

I have gone through [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/228), but no helps till now.

[image]

Comment: Hi. you must create an application on paypal site. Then choose environment(sandox or production) and add your client id of app.

Comment: I can givw you working code

Comment: @V.Kalyuzhnyu yes, i have done everything, creating app, copied CONFIG_CLIENT_ID and working with sandbox environment.

Comment: Recently i had a pleasure with integration paypal in my app

Comment: Please, wait a little.i will soon be at home and remember to give code and some other advice

Comment: Have you added all required activities and services of paypal to manifest?

Comment: http://my-files.ru/prerfi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks resolved now with new version 2.12.5**

Got this news from official android SDK github code, person from Paypal confirmed that it is now resolved. from [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/228)

> I have updated the okhttp version to latest stable release in v2.12.5.
>   Can you please update to latest version and confirm if you are now not
>   getting this exception.
>
> I was hardly able to reproduce this issue on any device, and so, would
>   need your help fixing this issue. I will keep an eye on this issue
>   promptly, and get it sorted out soon :+1:
>
> Thanks for helping all !

I have tested with new version 2.12.5 and problem is no more exist.

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5')
```